# how to get meta tags info of uploaded image in php?

Tags: php, metadata

I want to store Image meta tags information like creation date, city, state, country, caption,  keywords, description, copyright, author name, author title and so on.

Is there any class to get these information?

Comment: http://php.net/manual/en/book.exif.php

Answer (score 8, accepted):

try this:
http://php.net/manual/en/function.exif-read-data.php

Comment: Thanks @Nick, I tried it, Its giving me lot of information but only copyright and description from my requirement. I want to get all these information from the image. title, keywords, description, copyright, created_date, instructions, author_name, author_title, provider, source, city, state, country.

Comment: I would imagine then that there is missing data in your images. It looks to me like this PHP function should be pulling all this data as standard